# A conjecture about prime test

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

> **Conjecture** If $\varphi(m)<\varphi(n)$ for all $m<n$,then $n$ is a prime number.

I tried to find a counterexample when $n=pq$ ($p,q$ are prime), then we have to find a prime between $(p-1)(q-1)$ and $pq$, but I don't know if this is an open problem.

[I have posted the question in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4396224/884092)

Comment: This is roughly [Andrica's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrica%27s_conjecture) and is certainly open.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Is it equivalent？

Comment: @ReinhardtΩ , yes they are equivalent. If there are no primes between $pq$ and $(p-1)(q-1)$ then for two consecutive primes $p_r>pq>(p-1)(q-1)>p_{r-1}$, hence $\sqrt{p_r}-\sqrt{p_{r-1}}≥\sqrt{pq+1}-\sqrt{pq-(p+q)}>1$.

Comment: @AlapanDas Thanks!